# Run background process on post and poll for status with get/id in .net MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, iis

I have a page that will submit some data for processing to the server via a post. The page will then pull the server for the status of the processing until it the processing finishes via get requests. Once the processing is over the get request will return the result to the page.

The question is what frameworks are available in ASP for this? I do not want to have the request wait until processing is finished (No async controller). The page will poll the server periodically for the status and result.

The other issue I see is that the status of the process and the result will have to be stored in between polling. Are there any options besides setting up some external data store to hold the information between polls? e.g. some way temporally hold the data in the worker process of IIS as there are hoops to jump though to access Session from an API controller?

Comment: we use an ajax call for this.  Put it in a jquery timer that will fire a call to the server every 30 seconds or whatever you set,  once it goes true you can reload, return a partial something like that

Comment: This is a solid approach. In my case though we are a single page app so no reload. As I look into this it seems I may be able to store the data in Session. Though pass projects that used ViewState have me a little paranoid to do so.

Answer (score 1):

> The question is what frameworks are available in ASP for this?

There are no frameworks to do that. You will have to implement it yourself. If you decided to go the other way round, i.e. using PUSH notifications instead of POLLing at regular intervals you might checkout SignalR. If not, you will have to deal with new threads on the server.

> Are there any options besides setting up some external data store to
>   hold the information between polls? e.g. some way temporally hold the
>   data in the worker process of IIS as there are hoops to jump though to
>   access Session from an API controller?

No, there aren't. Storing such information in-memory is a terrible thing to do. This will never work in a web farm and don't forget that IIS might decide to recycle the application pool at any time, killing everything you might have stored so far in memory. The only reliable way to implement this is to have a centralized datastore which will be shared among the nodes of the web farm.

Comment: Luckily for me the result of the processing does not need to be persistent and once it's sent to the client can be deleted. When we do scale beyond this demo app and the data needs to persist we will use SQLServer20* or what ever storage is already in place. Threads are not a problem in themselves, my concern is that they may be aborted once the request returns a status. These are the higher level questions one hopes to find truth for when posting on SO.

Comment: Yes, in this case it would be better to use WebSockets and PUSH notifications. They are designed exactly for this purpose. Long running operations in threads are a big no-no in web applications simply because of the reasons you outlined in your comment -> they are not reliable and there's nothing that can guarantee you that a background thread you started will ever finish.

Comment: However if the request was instead pushed to a DB and then a service processed it and pushed the result back to the db where the get request ran a query to return the data, that would be fine. The point is that for a demo I'm not going to build out an entire architecture. Instead I need fill-ins that will be replaced with actual patterns later.

Comment: If that's for a demo, then don't worry. Just spin a new thread and store the information in-memory. I thought you were asking about a real application in which I would have used much more optimized techniques such as WebSockets which are designed exactly for those purposes.